# sphinx-build for two independent documents that share source files

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to generate two documents that share source files but are independent of each other. Below is my tree directory. I am not sure if I am taking the best approach, because when I open the HTML I see in the index tab the other guide. I guess what I am trying to do is to use one Makefile and conf.py file to generate both documents.

Thank you in advance,
Hellen

Tree directory of the project:

```
   <Top-directory>
   ├── Makefile
   ├── conf.py
   ├── index.rst
   ├── source
   │   ├── file1.rst
   │   ├── file2.rst
   │   ├── file3.rst
   │   └── file4.rst
   ├── admin_guide
   │   ├── index.rst
   │   ├── admin_file1.rst
   │   └── admin_file3.rst
   └── user_guide
       ├── index.rst
       ├── user_file1.rst
       └── user_file3.rst
```

Comment: Is the project directory structure presented here correct? Are `source` `admin_guide` and `source_guide` really not inside the top directory but next to it?